# What is an appropriate Microsoft solution to create a filesharing repository for only a subset of people at an organization?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, file-sharing, onedrive, sharepoint

Our organization has offices in different cities, and we want to create a filesharing solution only for people sitting at one particular office. Previously we used to have a Google drive folder and now we are moving to Microsoft-based and Office platforms.

What is the most appropriate solution here? Should we simply create a OneDrive folder and share it manually with each and everyone of the people at that particular office? Or use a SharePoint solution? Or a OneDrive Shared Library, Teams,...?

We have a mailing list dedicated for the people at our particular office, but as far as I understood it is not possible to share access on OneDrive with a mailinglist/distribution list.

Please note that the main goal is only to have a filesharing and document editing solution for a particular office (and not all people of the organization).

Comment: Good question. How many users would this be shared with, approximately?

Comment: about 50-55 users

Comment: Ok so quite a few users then. Do you know roughly how many GB of data will be on this share? And will all users have read/write access or will some have read only?

Comment: I'd say around 30GB and giving all users read&write access

Comment: Are these files generally pretty small? Mostly documents etc? Or are there some multiple-gigabye video files in there? Also, any idea what the download speed of the internet is at that site?

Comment: mix of all. Word documents and just a handful of 1GB videos

Comment: Any idea what the upload and download internet speeds are like at that site?

Comment: 200Mb/s download - 20 Mb/s upload

Answer (score 1):

Do you have Office 365 subscription? Maybe you can consider  the Collaborate feature of Office 365. Please refer to this link:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-with-office-365-ac05a41e-0b49-4420-9ebc-190ee4e744f4

Answer (score 0):

You can share a folder and in the security tab you can give permission just to the group/people(s) you want

Comment: Doing this from a regular Windows installation would cause users to hit the connection limit after the first 20 out of their 55 users attempted to browse the network share. File sharing from a Windows system isn't a viable solution without a server operating system, which would probably be overkill for this situation.

Comment: Don't you have a server that has SMB (NetApp, Windows server etc), If you have you can handle it using the permission (ACL) for each shared folder. Servers should handle hundred or ever thousands concurrent connections.

Answer (score 0):

We finally decided to use SharePoint for this, and it seems to be the right choice (so far) for our needs; especially considering its regular backup and version history features.

Thank you all for your tips and help! Appreciate that.